# How do I copy a document from one db to another (couchDB)

Tags: json, couchdb

It seems that I need to load a couchDB JSON document to the client and then post it to another couchdb database in order to copy it from one db to another? Or is there a server side method to do so?

**Reference**
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/documents.html#copy-db-doc
The copy command is non standard http and is within one db only.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `COPY`ing is only possible within single database, but you may replicate single or multiple documents instead:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"source": "db_a", "target":"db_b", "doc_ids": ["foo"]}'
```

However, you cannot change document ID in this case like you can with `COPY`. If you need this, `COPY` document first, replicate it and remove it in source if needed. Three HTTP API calls for using only server side methods and not loading document content to the client - decision to use it instead of having copy-logic on the client is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Using [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module.

Pre: The destination document exists in the DB. The origin attachment exists in the DB

```
var originAttachment = 'somefile.txt'
var originDocId = '1somecouchdbid';
var origindb = 'http://localhost:5984/db1';

var destinationAttachment = 'somefile.txt'
var destinationDocId = '2somecouchdbid';
var desinationdb = 'http://localhost:5984/db2';

var uridestination = desinationdb + "/" + destinationDocId;

request(uridestination, function(err, res, body){

if(err){
    throw err;
}

var doc = JSON.parse(body);

var origin =  origindb + '/' + originDocId + '/' + encodeURIComponent(originAttachment);

var optionsOrigin = {
    url: origin
};

var uridestination = desinationdb + '/' + destinationDocId + '/' + encodeURIComponent(destinationAttachment) + '?rev=' + doc._rev;

var optionDestination = { 
    url: uridestination,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': false
    }
};

request(optionsOrigin)
.pipe(request(optionsDestination, function(err, res, body){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(body);        
}));
});
```